# How do I map 1 column of a SINGLE table query to a COLLECTION using Spring JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Id like to know if there's a way of doing something **like the Stream API groupingBy Collector**. I know how to select one column (the question was marked as duplicated and I don't belive it is) I want to do a grouping (**like the groupingBy collector of the java Stream API**) not a group By.
Suppose you have a table (ONE table) like:

```
+---------------------+
+       myTable       +
+----------+----------+
+ column_A | column_B +
+----------+----------+
+        1 |        1 +
+        1 |        2 +
+        1 |        3 +
+        2 |        1 +
+----------+----------+
```

And I would like to have something like

```
@Entity
@Table("MyTable")
public class MyEntity {
  @Column("column_A")
  private int a;
  
  @Column("column_B") ?
  private List<Integer> b; //normanly this wuould just be int b, butI want a list of all b's that have the same a
}
```

with a repo like

```
public interface MyCrudRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity,Integer>{
  List<MyEntity> findByA();
}
```

or

```
public interface MyCrudRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity,Integer>{
  @Query("SELECT m.a,m.b FROM MyEntity m")
  List<MyEntity> customFind();
}
```

This is not necessarily how it should look at the end, anything that works similar to this is fine. I have looked into projections but all examples use 2 different tables.

Comment: Your question is not clear on what are you try to get. Please try providing some more clarification regarding the problem and the expected output

Comment: For one table with columns a and b, I want an object with 'a' and a list of all 'b's that share the same 'a'. This is similiar to what you would do if you had 2 tables using @OneToMany but I only have 1 table.

Answer (score 1):

There is no a specific way to do what you need using JPQL. Instead, you can use a Hibernate [ResultTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html), that allows yo to transform the query results to whatever you need. This is a code solution, and is similar to implementing the grouping using the Stream API in the list result and return a map containing the aggregated data.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to refer the same table using annotations (some kind of hack):

```
@ElementCollection  
@CollectionTable(name = "table_name")
```

Example:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name = "parent",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private List<Child> children;


    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class Child {
        @Column(name = "child_id")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "child_name")
        private String name;
    }
}
```

Columns in the table:

```
id, name, child_id, child_name
```

But... you'll get several copies from repository (one object for row), so use Set to get rid of them `Set.copyOf(repository.findAll())`

Hibernate will be querying database to get children for each parent.

P.S. Should work with `@OneToMany` annotation too, possibly, if create two entities for one table, didn't check that